# JTextField, does not update parsed data from a file/serial port

Tags: java, swing, port, jtextfield, dynamic-arrays

This is a code that captures the serial port data and transfer it to the GUI frame in the JTextField.
I used the terminal console to check if all data were captured, it captured all of the data. 
When I added the str0.setText(cell[0]) in the scanner, the flow of data stops at cell0, and what appears to the frame are only the 2 cells (cell 0 and cell 1 data) then it freezes.

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;
    import java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ContainerAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.ContainerEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
    import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JSpinner;
    import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
    import javax.swing.JTextPane;

    public class DisplayTest1 extends JFrame implements  TextListener {
        public JTextField txtTextfield_31;//57600
        public JTextField str0;
        public JTextField str1;
        public JTextField str2;
        public JTextField str3;
        public JTextField str4;
        public JTextField str5;
        public JTextField str6;
        public JTextField str7;
        public JTextField str8;
        public JTextField str9;
        public JTextField txtTextfield;//COM3
        public int cd;
        public String textField;

        public String cell0;
        public String cell1;
        public String cell2;
        public String cell3;
        public String cell4;
        public String cell5;
        public String cell6;
        public String cell7;
        public String cell8;
        public String cell9;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox bd;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DroneDisplayTest1 frame = new DroneDisplayTest1();
                        frame.setResizable(false);
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                         new JTextField().setVisible(true);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

str0 = new JTextField(40);
        str0.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                str0.getText();
                str0.setText(cell0);

            }
        });
        str0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                str0.getText();
                str0.setText(cell0);
            }
        });
        /*str0.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent arg0) {
                str0.getText();
                str0.updateUI();    
                str0.setText(cell0);

            }});
        */
        str0.addInputMethodListener(new InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent arg0) {

            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent arg0) {
                str0.getText();
                str0.setText(cell0);
            }
        });

        /*str0.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent arg0) {
                            }
        });
        */
        str0.setEditable(false);
        str0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        str0.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        str0.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        str0.setColumns(10);//TIME
        str0.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        str0.setBounds(545, 115, 251, 20);
        getContentPane().add(str0);



        str1 = new JTextField(40);
        str1.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
                str1.getText();
                //str1.updateUI();  
                str1.setText(cell1);
            }
        });
    str1.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent arg0) {
                str1.getText();
                str1.updateUI();    
                str1.setText(cell1);
            }
        });
        str1.setEditable(false);
        str1.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent arg0) {
                str1.setText(cell1);
            }
        });

        str1.addInputMethodListener(new InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent arg0) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent arg0) {
                str1.getText();
                str1.setText(cell1);
                            }
        });

        str1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                pink();
                str1.getText();
                str1.add(getStr1());
                str1.setText(cell1);
            }
        });

        str1.setBounds(180, 114, 162, 21);
        str1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        str1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        str1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        str1.setColumns(10);//GPS LATITUDE
        str1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //str1.setText("35.214153");
        contentPane.add(str1);

public void pink () {
        SerialPort dronePorts [] = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        try{
            SerialPort port  = dronePorts[0];
                if (port.openPort())
                port.setBaudRate(57600);
                port.setNumDataBits(8);
                port.setParity(0);
                port.setNumStopBits(1);

                System.out.println("PortName: " + "Port" + " is connected ");

                port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING,0,0);

         // open file   
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());
        // read each line in the file

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String [] cell = line.split(",");

            //this where u put the label to capture the data.
     String b = "TIME, LAT, LONG, RSSI, PH,ENB, ET, IV, RV, TEMP";
     String [] stre = b.split(",");
        stre [0] =  "TIME : " ;
        stre [1] = "GPS LATITUDE : ";
        stre [2] = "GPS LONGITUDE : ";
        stre [3] = "RSSI : ";
        stre [4] = "PHASE : ";
        stre [5] = "EPC No. OF BYTES : ";
        stre [6] = "EPC TAGBYTES : ";
        stre [7] = "INPUT VOLTAGE : ";
        stre [8] = "RFID VOLTAGE : ";
        stre [9] = "TEMPERATURE : "; 


         if(cell.length > 7){
            System.out.println("")  ;
            System.out.println("NewLine-Inside the pinkDroneDisplayTest")   ;

            for(int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)    {
            System.out.println(stre[i]+cell[i]);        

            //THIS IS WORKING, problem how to transfer the str to the frame
            str0.setText(cell[0]);  
            str1.setText(cell[1]);  
            str2.setText(cell[2]);  
            str3.setText(cell[3]);  
            str4.setText(cell[4]);  
            str5.setText(cell[5]);  
            str6.setText(cell[6]);  
            str7.setText(cell[7]);  
            str8.setText(cell[8]);  
            str9.setText(cell[9]);
                    }}};

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Unable to connect to Port");
            }
                return;
        }
```

Comment: 1) (Just a guess, but..) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, ..

Comment: .. or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: thank  you, I appreciate your time looking into this.I set the JTextField from a different method (pink), how can I get the object inside the (cell[i]), and update JTextField automatically.